# Qual é a finalidade do $_REQUEST?

Tags: php

De acordo com o Manual do PHP:

> A variável `$_REQUEST` é um array associativo que por padrão contém informações de $_GET, $_POST e $_COOKIE.

Sendo assim, essa variáveis é uma espécie de mistura.

Qual é a finalidade de se obter tantos dados da requisição `POST` como `GET` e afins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A superglobal [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) reúne todos os valores presentes nas superglobais `$_GET`, `$_POST` e `$_COOKIE` em um único array associativo.

Caso haja um ou mais valores presentes em mais de uma superglobal, eles são preenchidos em `$_REQUEST` de acordo com a diretiva [`request_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order):

> This directive describes the order in which PHP registers GET, POST and Cookie variables into the _REQUEST array. Registration is done from left to right, newer values override older values.
>   If this directive is not set, variables_order is used for $_REQUEST contents.
>   Note that the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns.

O valor da diretiva `variables_order` por padrão é `GC`, ou seja, primeiro são levados em conta os valores de `$_GET` e, em seguida, os valores de `$_POST`, para se preencher os valores de `$_REQUEST.`

Comment: Se eu quisesse pegar tudo, era mais fácil dar um `array_merge($_POST, $_GET)`. O PHP é meio doido mesmo

Comment: Não necessariamente. Se seu servidor estiver configurado para que só a superglobal `$_REQUEST` esteja disponível (por meio da diretiva `variables_order`), você não poderia fazer isso.

Comment: Aí eu teria que poder acessar o `ini_set` ou o `php.ini`. Mas a idéia é válida!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters `$_REQUEST` = 9 caracteres, `array_merge($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE)` = 36

Answer (score 1):

O `$_REQUEST` é o tipo genérico de `$_GET, $_POST,$_COOKIE` para ela tanto faz se seus dados estão vindo via $_GET ou $_POST ela resgata ambos, seu uso é pouco recomendado.

**Por que seu uso não é recomendado?**

O motivo maior é segurança, imagine que você tenha um formulário na página `pagina1.php` que será enviado para `pagina2.php`.

Se você utilizar o **$_REQUEST** os dados podem ser passados direto por querys string,  então sua aplicação estará sujeita a ataques.

Veja a nota que está no manual do PHP:

> As variáveis em $_REQUEST são providas para o script via mecanismos de entradas GET, POST, e COOKIE e portando poderia ser
>   modificadas por um usuário remoto e não podem ser confiadas. A
>   presença e ordem das variáveis listadas neste array é definido de
>   acordo com a diretiva de configuração do PHP variables_order.

Então, se tanto faz se seus dados forem mandados via get ou post use `$_REQUEST` do contrário esquece-a.

Referencias : [$_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST onde, quando e como](http://soudev.com/developer/php/3/-_get-_post-_request-onde-quando-e-como)